# strange directories on ubuntu 13.10 btrfs partition

Tags: ubuntu, btrfs

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 (ext4) and installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a partition of its own (sda2) with btrfs. I had no time to configure 13.10 to my work environment (yet), so I mounted `/dev/sda2` from 12.04 and want to benchmark from there.

But I see directories `@` and `@home` in the root, not the usual `/dev`,  `/usr`, `/lib` I am used to. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the default (for Ubuntu) subvolumes: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs#Ubuntu-specific_subvolume_layout_in_11.04_and_later

You should take care that 12.04 does not have a [recommended kernel](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Getting_started) for `btrfs`, 13.10 does have one. There might be performance differences.